# Unable to start spark on master URL

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spring-data

I am building a REST microservice with spark and Cassandra and I provided spark master value as local and its running fine.

But when I tried to provide spark master URL as " spark://ip:7077 " then it's showing the following error when I start the rest service:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 5099964663881645984 to /98.8.150.125:7077: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageWithHeader.touch(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/netty/util/ReferenceCounted;
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.lambda$sendRpc$2(TransportClient.java:237) ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.2.2.jar!/:2.2.2]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyOutboundHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:837) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:740) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:816) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:302) ~[netty-handler-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1081) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1128) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1070) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.protocol.MessageWithHeader.touch(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/netty/util/ReferenceCounted;
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.touch(ReferenceCountUtil.java:77) ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:116) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:810) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:111) ~[netty-codec-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738) ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I am using following spark and cassandra dependencies for my rest service:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cassandra.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.sql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.sql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.cassandra.connector.unshaded.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also tried to provide spark master URL in spark-env.sh in spark conf, but its no use. Has anyone faced similar issue before?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found it (after so many hit and trials and research). It is an issue with spark 2.2.2. Spark still supports netty 4.0 version and since it was internally dependent on netty 4.1 libraries in my application, therefore there was a conflict between two versions. I just added netty 4.0 dependency and its working fine now.

Here is more detail about the issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21143?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK%20AND%20text%20~%20abstractmethoderror